# Qt SVG Generator vector accuracy limited to pixel size?

Tags: c++, qt, svg, qpainter

I'm using QPainter and QSvgGenerator to generate a set of symbologies that I need vector accuracy on. I have a series of controls to set up the generation of the shapes and I'm drawing them using QPainter.  My ultimate goal is a mathematically accurate SVG vector image, but I only seem to be getting pixel level accuracy from QPainter to SVG Generator. When I calculate the positions of my lines, I'm not sure if QPainter is rounding to the nearest whole pixel position, but I'm drawing the symbology in a 512x512 widget space.  This of course gives me a 512x512 pixel svg, with the lines snapped to the nearest pixel instead of the actual double precision floating point x/y values I calculated...

If I want an accurate Vector image, should I just dump all of my points into a buffer and write my own SVG generator or is there a way to get double precision vector accuracy with QPainter to SVG Generator with a display size of only 512x512?

Answer (score 0):

Solved this by using QPointF instead of ints for X and Y.

```
    painter.drawLine(QPointF(pX1, pY1), QPointF(pX2, pY2));
```